# Would the following case be considered as "voting irregularities"?

Tags: discussion, voting, voting-fraud

Consider a hypothetical scenario.

Person A does not like few people on SO for whatever reason, let's call them Person B and C. Now, what person A does is whenever any of B or C answers he goes and upvotes other people's answer on the same post. So for example, if for a particular question there are 3 answers by B, Y and Z. Person A would upvote Y and Z's answers and not B's. Person A does the same thing with C as well. It does not matter what the quality of the answer is posted by other people, A upvotes their answers irrespective. Some answers were posted by new contributors asking more clarification from the OP and they were still upvoted by A. This also isn't restricted to only one answer. This is done on every answer posted by B or C where there is another answer present in the post.

This behaviour has some short term effects and impacts how other people see those answers. Morally, IMO this is not a correct behaviour. We should upvote/downvote solely based on content of the answer. What I would like to understand is that does this fall under "voting irregularities" or if any action can be take against such behaviour?

Comment: note that this can backfire. Other visitors seeing a good answer with less votes, and bad answers with more votes would correct the voting. It may help B & C, but random upvotes on other answers are problematic

Comment: How do you learned that it is A who is voting on those posts? Why can't it be someone else?

Comment: The evidence for this would probably have to be stronger than "we saw they were online, so the suspicion falls to them". As Ed says in an answer below, a Stack Overflow DBA can be approached to write a query to run on the production databases, but mods tend to filter requests so that they are not bothered with trivial/unfounded suspicions.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This seems like a pretty niche case and very difficult to prove, but yes, I would consider it a "voting irregularity."

Any voting that is obviously not based on post quality is inappropriate. We don't second-guess people's votes when they are voting on post quality but doing so incompetently or incorrectly (*e.g.*, voting for incorrect, incomplete, or misleading answers). But if someone is trying to skew vote totals in *any* way, especially by voting for non-answers and other junk, then that's a problem.

If you see this, please raise a custom flag. Let us know who you think is behind the strange voting and why. We, the ♦ moderators, will have to bring it to the attention of the community managers (SO staff). We can't see who voted for which posts, but SO's developers and DBAs can.

Comment: I will wait for anyone else to post an answer so I can vote for them:)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Note that this can backfire :-P

Comment: You mean you haven't seen "don't upvote known spammers" comments?

Comment: @Joshua I’m not sure whom you mean by “you,” but that kind of comment isn’t really relevant to this situation. It’s not about the decision not to vote for a particular answer; it’s about the decision to vote for every other answer to make one particular answer look worse.

Answer (score 4):

As the answer of [Ed Cottrell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385467/1536976) already says, every vote that is not based on the merit of the contribution itself is a voting irregularity. But since nobody here can see who votes for whom the best way to detect these irregularities is probably by automated algorithms on the database. The question is probably then, how sensitive these automated algorithms currently are to these kind of voting irregularities? That's probably a question for the staff.

How could it work?

Look for correlations in the voting patterns. For example take every combination of two accounts and see if their down-/up-votes correlate, then do some statistical testing against the hypothesis that voting is random around a given general quality of a user (which may change smoothly over time or be tag specific). In order to include your specific kind of irregularities count up-votes on answers also partly as down-votes on non-up-voted answers. The scaling factor (how much of a virtual down-vote an up-vote to another answer is) is probably crucial, I would start with 0.1 maybe. Since the algorithm used anyway is secret, I leave the details to those who implement it. :)

Undoing is also a problem. Do you just want to undo the likely fraud voting  or just any voting from a user who likely participated in fraud voting somewhere? The latter is easier to implement but might do too much, the former may be more difficult to achieve. But in principle you could probably try to nullify part of the votes of a user so that the correlations in the voting pattern are reduced and the statistical test doesn't give a positive result anymore.

Some observations: The test will probably fail if the person doing the fraud will generally be an up-voter and up-votes also a lot of other contributions. It will also fail if groups of people up-vote themselves (since you test only pairs of users) or if somebody has a grudge against many people.

Comment: iirc the current algo is largely time based. You could get a representative sample for finding this out by using SEDE sleuthing to detect voting corrected events and filtering out the ones that don't occur at 03:00 daily.

Comment: @Magisch I don't know the current algo and I don't want to reverse engineer it. Time based may fail here because it's the same for normal voting behavior. I too often up-vote several answers to the same question at the same time. The idea is mainly to count up-votes on answers as partly down-votes on all other answers in the fraud detection algorithm.